# Attempting to Load images in Javascript before game starts

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

So I'm making a website with a simple flappy bird clone using HTML, CSS, JS with a Flask backend. Everything was working fine except that I noticed that if the images, weren't cached, the game was all messed up(the game needs width and height variables of the images to place the objects in the world).

To fix this I was trying to prevent the game from starting until all of the images and 3 sounds were loaded before it can continue.

this function is called like so

`assets = loadAssets(namesArray,pathArray,setUpGame);`

the game gets held up when loading the 3 sounds, i'm sure the paths are correct as before implementing this solution the sounds were loaded and worked fine. When I inspect element using a chrome the sounds are not there

```
function loadAssets(names, files, onAllLoaded){
    console.log('Loading Images');
    var i = 0, numLoading = names.length;
    console.log('Assets to Load: ' + numLoading);
    const onload = () => {
        numLoading -= 1;
        console.log(' finished loading, ' + numLoading + ' left.');
        if(numLoading === 0) onAllLoaded()
    }

    const images = {};
    while (i < names.length) {
        if(names[i] === 'fly' || names[i] === 'hit' || names[i] === 'score'){
            const snd = images[names[i]] = new Audio();
            console.log('Loading ' + names[i]  + '   ' + files[i] + '.mp3');
            snd.src = "/static/sounds/" + files[i] + ".mp3";
            snd.onload = onload;
            i++;
        }else{
            const img = images[names[i]] = new Image();
            console.log('Loading ' + files[i] + '.png');
            img.src = "/static/images/" + files[i] + ".png";
            img.onload = onload;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return images;
}
```

this solution I found online somewhere seemed to work until I added in sounds, for those curious the output looks like in the chrome console

https://pastebin.com/C1UWSyma

anyhelp would be appreciated

Comment: Just start the game after all the page is loaded.   window.addEventListener('load', () => { YOUR GAME STARTUP HERE }    An example I worked here. http://php-dev.epizy.com/game.html

Comment: You mention both images and sounds in your question. To clarify, which do you need to wait for before loading the game?